# JLabel with multiple lines and alignment to the right

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I searched through many posts and figured out that `JLabel` supports HTML.
So I can do

```
JLabel search  = new JLabel("<html>Search<br/> By:</html>");
```

to get multiple lines. Above code will result in

```
Search  
By:
```

However, What I want is something like

```
Search  
   By:
```

Adding spaces before "By:" will work only when the window is not resizable(And very silly lol).
Can anyone tell me how to modify this code to make it work as I wanted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slightly simpler HTML than seen in @MadProgrammer's answer:

```
new JLabel("<html><body style='text-align: right'>Search<br>By:");
```

Comment: "div" works well too: new JLabel("<html><div style='text-align: right'>Search<br/>By:</div></html>");

Answer (score 3):

Non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) are supported:

```
new JLabel("<html>Search<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; By:</html>");
```

If you want to have real right-alignment, use individual right-aligned labels and combine them:

```
JLabel search = new JLabel("Search", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
JLabel by = new JLabel("By:", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

JPanel combined = new JPanel();
combined.setOpaque(false);
combined.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
combined.add(search);
combined.add(by);
```

or use a read-only `JTextPane` instead (with `\n` for line breaks):

```
JTextPane text = new JTextPane();

SimpleAttributeSet attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(attributes, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attributes, "Default");
text.setParagraphAttributes(attributes, true);
text.setEditable(false);
text.setOpaque(false);
text.setText("Search\nBy:");
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you might achieve this, one of the safer ways might be to use a `<table>` and aligning both cells to the right...

[image: Label wrapped in table]

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "<html><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>" + 
                                "<tr><td align='right'>Search</td></tr>" +
                                "<tr><td align='right'>By:</td></tr></table>"
);
```

This overcomes issues with differences between fonts and font rendering on different platforms