# How to use .txt lines for a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need to take the first 10 lines from the link fixed to `address` so I can put them into a JLabel for GUI. I separated with `line.split("\\s+")` but I can't figure out how to move the first 10 lines into the Label since I am using it within a while loop.

```
try{   
                String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
                URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
                Scanner in = new Scanner (pageLocation.openStream()); 
                String line = ""; //intialize
                int i = 0; 

                while(i < 10){ //add limit for 10
                   line = in.nextLine(); //take line
                   String[] content = line.split("\\s+"); //seperate by multiple spaces
                   i++; //count another country
                }

                }
                catch (IOException exception){
                    System.out.println("File not Found");
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the text in html? For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550524/jlabel-with-multiple-lines-and-alignment-to-the-right/29551195#29551195)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Have you tried combining the string instead of assigning each line to a new array position? Also try using a `JTextPane` or `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create the array outside the loop and add the splitted lines to it.

```
    try {
        String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
        URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
        String line = ""; // intialize
        int i = 0;
        String[] panelContent = new String[10];
        while (i < 10) { // add limit for 10
            line = in.nextLine(); // take line
            // seperate by multiple spaces, but must be more than one
            // because some countrys have composed names like United States
            String lineContent[] = line.split("\\s\\s+");
            panelContent[i] = String.format("%s %s %s", lineContent[0], lineContent[1], lineContent[2]);
            i++; // count another country
        }
        // Here you have de content to populate de JLabel
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(panelContent));

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("File not Found");
    }
```