# Java GUI | Ordered List

Tags: java, list, user-interface

I'm creating a Gui. In my Gui I want to create a numbered list.

The list I would like to use is not a JList. Its more somthing like in HTML: `<ol>`.

**How do I create such a numbered list with a JLable in Java Gui?**

I appreciate all anwers.
:)

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: how to create a Ordered list in Java Swing

Comment: How about creating a JLabel and populating it with html list type data?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand that @Prashant what do you mean?

Comment: Many Swing components support html rendering, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550524/jlabel-with-multiple-lines-and-alignment-to-the-right/29551195#29551195)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    static class Frame extends JFrame {
        private static final String HTML_CONTENT = "<html><body><ol><li>one</li><li>Two</li></body></html>";

        JPanel panel = (JPanel)this.getContentPane();

        Frame () {
            this.pack();
            JLabel label = new JLabel (HTML_CONTENT);
            this.panel.add(label);
            this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Here passing the value of the label as html is important.